# How to show circular progress indicator while uploading image

Tags: flutter, progress-indicator, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I'm new on flutter this is my code.

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('users')
            .child(widget.user.uid)
            .child('$clotheId.jpg');
        await ref.putFile(_pickedImage!);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an variable `bool isUploaded = false;`
And apply condition that
`isUploaded ?  Text("Uploded Succesful") : CircularProcessIndicator(),`

In which method you are uploading then set:

```
final ref = 
    FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('users')
    .child(widget.user.uid)
    .child('$clotheId.jpg');
    await ref.putFile(_pickedImage!).then((value) {setState((){isUploaded = true; });});
```

Comment: Show what you want to sbow in place of text

Comment: I'm uploading the images in a button, where I apply the condition?

Comment: You can apply this condition on the button if button is clicked then change the button to circularprpcessindicator so that the button can't pressed again otherwise updoading will be twice or may you get any error